# Angular2 child component deleting

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have an angular application, and I'm having an issue.  I have a (parent) component that has an array of items, for each item there is a sub (child) component.  The child components each have a button (and function) to delete themselves, but the parent component is not being notified of this event taking place.

I'm not sure what is the proper way to delete the child component in such away that the parent component removes it from the view.  I am currently just calling `delete this.product` (product is one of the items in the parent array) which does indeed remove it from the parent array, but the parent array does not update.

Comment: Look into @Output() with EventEmitter.  Then you can have the parent listen for child events.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could implement this this way in the child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{element.name}}
      <span (click)="deleteElement()">Delete</span>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  element: any;
  @Output()
  elementDeleted: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  deleteElement() {
    this.elementDeleted.emit();
  }
}
```

And leverage this event in the parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <child *ngFor="#element of elements" [element]="element"
             (elementDeleted)="onElementDeleted(element)">
      </child>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.elements = [
      { name: 'element1' },
      { name: 'element2' },
      (...)
    ];
  }

  onElementDeleted(element) {
    var index = this.elements.findIndex((elt) => (elt===element));
    if (index != -1) {
      this.elements.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the difference between using `inputs: ['element']` in the `@Component` section above, and using `@Input()` inside the class itself?

Comment: You need to do `(elementDeleted)="onElementDeleted($event)"` in the template (instead of `(elementDeleted)="onElementDeleted(element)"`). This probably changed since you posted the answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. Everything seems fine until I reach angular's change detection - it compares elements variable before and after splicing and detects inconsistence when deleted element is not the LAST one of elements array. It deletes both component request to be deleted and all that are before on the list of elements.